# skobbler how i can save in my app a json downloaded from my profile?

Tags: ios, iphone, offline-mode, skmaps

I'm trying to use skobbler to create an app that download and then works offline with some predefinited maps. I have created this maps in my developer account , i can download a Json after a click on "Use" Button beside the map. Now don't know how i can use this json, i'm using the skobbler demo ios app and i can't found a method like :

[Download the map with this json: [the json i have downloaded from my profile]].

I have read the online documentation, but i am a little bit confusing. I have read the code in demo app but it seems to download only a predefined list of map:

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
                NSArray *packages = [appDelegate.skMapsObject packagesForType:SKTPackageTypeContinent];
                MapJSONViewController *mapXMLVC = [[MapJSONViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapJSONViewController" bundle:nil withSKMapPackages:packages];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapXMLVC animated:YES];
```

Any idea? I my map creator online i have added some pins, i wanna use the same pins in my offline app. Open the json i have see no reference to pins...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow this blog post:

http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/creating-an-app-with-a-pre-bundled-map/

It is described there how can you build in desired maps